# Make non suspicious cURL

Tags: php, curl

I'm trying to use PHP cURL from my shared hosting to get information from other domain website.

```
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_URL, $url);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, true);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_USERAGENT, "Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 10.0; WOW64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/51.0.2704.103 Safari/537.36");
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_REFERER, "https://google.com");
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_AUTOREFERER, true);
```

here is my options. The problem is that website recognizes that it is a bot. I tried to fill information from my own browser, but I guess it doesn't work if I send request from a shared hosting.

So how can I set correct, or at least not suspicious information, that website would allow my request?

Comment: you basically would have to duplicate EVERYTHING your browser does when browsing that site. e.g. if they have some JS code on that page, curl won't execute it, and if that js code contains "I am not a bot"-type confirmation code, they'll know you're scraping.

Comment: The thing is, that this cURL worked well, but then I did some loop which executed multiple requests in a very short time, so I guess that was the key in blocking me. The loop is removed now, but this cURL still doesn't work. Is there any chance that website somehow blaclisted me? By the way, website is pornhub if that is important.

Comment: @MarcB Obfuscating the JS strings will be the smallest problem.

Comment: talk to pornhub, then. if they blacklisted you, then there's nothing you can do to get around it, and shouldn't try. and most sites take a dim view of scraping anyways.

Comment: If you are blacklisted, first move would be change to a webspace with an other IP (apart from talking to target hoster).

Comment: Actually, giving you the bot-blacklist treatment would be the kindest form of rebuttal, you got lucky. I can think of half-a-dozen other means they could have used to escalate your life to  `very difficult`.

Comment: What do you mean? They can sue me?